# Microservices Intercomunication using Api Gateway

Tags: api, microservices

I'm building an ecosystem of microservices using an Api Gateway; I know that the Gateway is useful for Cachine, Auth, etc etc ... ok. Got it.
My issue arise when I try to let one microservice to comunicate with another one.
Let I have Api Gateway ( AG ), Microservice A ( MA ) and Microservice B ( MB )
I have to call MA:

Client -> AG -> MA

I have to call MB from MA in a syncronous way ( async is well known, we push on a queue ); which is the best solution for this?

Opt 1: calling MB from MA

This is the easy way and the faster; I call MB from MA directly, but MA has to know MB location, etc etc .

OPT2: calling AG from MA and MB from AG

MA call the AG who redirect the call to the MB. We have to call AG but we can centralize the discovery of the services. The drawback is that AG will be called many times

How do you usually solve this issue? Do you use AG also for ALL you internal call between microservices?

Thanks

Comment: generally what i have seen - external API are exposed via API Gateway , then API gateway passes those API calls to Load Balancers of Individual Microservice like MA LB  and MB LB and now when you need to call from MB to MA you know MB Load Balancer address and you call it

Comment: so, for you if I want to call MA from MB, I need to call AG first, not MA directly, right?

Comment: no you can call Load Balancer of MA from MB, the arch. is there is a API gateway then a Load Balancer and then your service

Comment: if I call MA from MB, MB has to know the location of MA, and any changes on MA host should be reflected in all services ... if I call AG from MB, only AG has to know the location of MA.